# Is there a standard way to allow consumers of a static library to define functions used within the library (C)

Tags: c, compilation, linker, embedded, static-libraries

### The Question

**Is there an "idiomatic" or standard way (in C) to allow consumers of a static library to "inject" custom code into it at well defined points in order to provide behavior specific to the consumer?**

### Background

I'm coming across the need to do things like this in a lot of code that I'm writing on a project...for example, I am writing code for a microcontroller on a custom SOM board that is able to be plugged into various different motherboards, each of which have various different sensors and actuators on them. We wrote a boot loader that, depending on which motherboard the SOM is plugged into, can detect and boot the correct application that knows how to use that motherboard.

All these applications might want to share common components, yet also define their own non-shared custom components.

As such, the project is structured as a "multitarget project" where we have an organization similar to the following:

```
lib/
  somelib1/
  somelib2/

common/
  chip_drivers // from silicon vendor
  SOM_drivers  // HW drivers for stuff on the SOM
  reuseable_business_logic // don't want to copy-paste into each app

apps/
  app1/ 
    app1_layer1/
    app1_layer2/
    main.c

  app2/
    app2_layer1/
    app2_layer2/
    main.c
```

I imagine that items in the `lib/` and `common/` directories should be compiled as static libraries and linked against both app images. **However, what if something in `common/reusable_business_logic` needs to depend on a function "exported" by an application?** Most of the `reusable_business_logic` code is truly portable, however it may need to eventually call a custom `app_send()` function that varies depending on whether it is linked against app1 or app2 (defined at application layer).

### Attempted Solution

**The way I'm imagining doing this is to have the `common/reusable_business_logic` layer call an unimplemented function that could be resolved at link time.** So, functions in the common layer would define `extern some_type app_send(some_type)` as **extern** in the common header file and then use it freely throughout the code. Meanwhile while app1 and app2, the consumers of the common business logic, would need to define their own respective implementation of this function in order to build.

But this feels messy and wrong. Is there a better or more idiomatic way to accomplish what I'm setting out to do?

Comment: Caller-supplied callbacks?

Comment: @jamesdlin how can there be any other way? Shellcode?

Comment: @jamesdlin that is a good point, I had thought about an approach like that. Some inherent drawbacks for that would be that the shared code would become stateful (e.g. consumer needs to initialize it and then own the handle to it throughout its lifetime. Introduces potential reentrancy issues depending on implementation). That said, the callback approachh is probably a much better implementation choice for the contrived example I used, and I'll ponder how refactoring the common code could use a callback scheme. Please post that as an answer, I'd be happy to upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this done one of two ways:

First, as mentioned in comments, callbacks. This is pretty widely used and simple to implement. Just passing function pointers to the common code at the time of initialization can be a perfectly valid way to go, though it does introduce state that might not otherwise need to be of concern.

Second pretty much what you've already tried - project specific headers. In essence, the common code just has a header/a set of headers declaring the prototypes for the functions that the target specific code will need to implement (usually, separated from the headers used by the common code itself) and those headers are used by the individual implementations, which each define the required functions. The library will be missing the definition of the target specific functions, but that doesn't really change much of anything - as long as there is a definition for all of the used functions by time the final executable is being linked, there really shouldn't be any problem. This is neither an uncommon nor a particularly bad solution to the problem that you're solving; it's pretty explicitly supported by the tools, and manages to solve the problem without really any overhead - the resulting binary is the same as if the reusable components were all copied into each project and used directly, without needing to do that.

A variant on the second option is to use weak symbols (declared as `__attribute__((weak))` in GCC at least, and potentially declared differently under different compilers) - this lets you have default implementations for the target specific functionality, included in the library itself - this really doesn't change anything, but can be useful if, most of the targets will just need a "default" implementation but some will require specific differences - this way, you can avoid re-writing the default for all of the implementations that would use it.

I've personally preferred the second option when I've had to use it for situations like you're describing due to the lower potential for issues at runtime, but the first option can be more flexible in certain cases, since the function pointers can be swapped to change functionality at runtime rather than compile time.

Answer (score 0):

In our automotive ECUs, we use AUTOSAR with its abstraction by MCAL and higher layer HW abstraction and services based on channels and the RTE with SW components and its ports and interfaces.

Another AUTOSAR feature is the possible split between PRECOMPILE, LINKTIME and POSTBUILD configuration.

So you could split configuration from standard implementation.

That allows also for physical channels (wired HW) and logical channels mapped to the physcial channels and the logical channel behaviour based on their ChannelId. Also Frames/ PDUs are abstracted by PduIds and its configured callouts in each config.

In the boot / startup phase, we have a certain detection mechanism, which could e.g. use a generic "unknown" configuration, which allows detection, after it does a partial shutdown and reconfiguration with the final startup initialization and configuration, e.g. reconfiguring the communication stack for left/right ECU (incl. routing in one or both ECUs between channels, turning a channel of, because it is not connected on the other ECU), having on both ECUs a PWM output, which is used in one position to drive a buzzer while it drives a heater or LED on another ECU.

AUTOSAR CompilerAbstraction allows to abstract the compiler differences away, e.g. `__attribute__` vs `#pragma` or `@far`/`@near` and not pollute the code with such different compiler specific handling over #ifdefs etc.

AUTOSAR MemoryMapping allows to place CODE / CONST / CONFIG_DATA (BSW configuration) / VAR (data) into separate memory sections, e.g. to split CODE from CONFIG_DATA into separately reprogrammable flash sections.

For your business logic, try to figure out library implementations of algorithms, like Debounce, P/PI/PID controller etc, where the config and state are passed in together with value.

The advantage of AUTOSAR is, you do not have to keep all the configurable parts in valuable RAM, like the here so often mentioned "pass the callback function by pointer", because you have to maintain these callbacks in RAM.

And you can actually create different configurations in AUTOSAR usually by a configuration and generation tool.

Yes, AUTOSAR also has drawbacks, which are normal in architectures introducing abstractions .. It requires a bit more resources.

In your example, the drivers and business_logic would have configurations, which are generated actually per application separately in your app1/app2, linking channels and application together. The configs are loaded then by you main.c files at initialization time.

```
apps/
    app1/ 
        app1_layer1/
        app1_layer2/
        config/      <-- driver/business logic config app1
        main.c

    app2/
        app2_layer1/
        app2_layer2/
        config/      <-- driver/business logic config app2
        main.c
```